# Using Google Translate in C#

Tags: c#, google-translate

I have to translate some text with Google's translate service. All code I've found doesn't work. I think because they have changed their service. If someone has working code, I would be very glad.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

See if this works for you

**google-language-api-for-dotnet**

http://code.google.com/p/google-language-api-for-dotnet/

**Google Translator**

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/GoogleTranslator.aspx

**Translate your text using Google Api's**

http://blogs.msdn.com/shahpiyush/archive/2007/06/09/3188246.aspx

**Calling Google Ajax Language API for Translation and Language Detection from C#**

http://www.esotericdelights.com/post/2008/11/Calling-Google-Ajax-Language-API-for-Translation-and-Language-Detection-from-C.aspx

**Translation Web Service in C#**

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/translation.aspx

Using Google's Translation API from .NET

http://www.reimers.dk/blogs/jacob_reimers_weblog/archive/2008/06/18/using-google-s-translation-api-from-net.aspx

Comment: Last link seems dead.

Answer (score 23):

The reason the first code sample doesn't work is because the layout of the page changed.  As per the warning on that page: "The translated string is fetched by the RegEx close to the bottom. This could of course change, and you have to keep it up to date."
I think this should work for now, at least until they change the page again.

```
public string TranslateText(string input, string languagePair)
{
    string url = String.Format("http://www.google.com/translate_t?hl=en&ie=UTF8&text={0}&langpair={1}", input, languagePair);
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
    webClient.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
    string result = webClient.DownloadString(url);
    result = result.Substring(result.IndexOf("<span title=\"") + "<span title=\"".Length);
    result = result.Substring(result.IndexOf(">") + 1);
    result = result.Substring(0, result.IndexOf("</span>"));
    return result.Trim();
}
```

Comment: How should I pass languagePair.. Please give me an example

Comment: @Naresh : pass it as : en|hi .en for English and hi for Hindi.

Comment: update: this trick does not work anymore

Answer (score 20):

I found this code works for me:

```
public String Translate(String word)
{
    var toLanguage = "en";//English
    var fromLanguage = "de";//Deutsch
    var url = $"https://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/single?client=gtx&sl={fromLanguage}&tl={toLanguage}&dt=t&q={HttpUtility.UrlEncode(word)}";
    var webClient = new WebClient
    {
        Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8
    };
    var result = webClient.DownloadString(url);
    try
    {
        result = result.Substring(4, result.IndexOf("\"", 4, StringComparison.Ordinal) - 4);
        return result;
    }
    catch
    {
        return "Error";
    }
}
```

Comment: This code works perfect but for Arabic text you just need to add this 
 webClient.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)");

Comment: Not entirely perfect though, the API will bring error 503 after heavier usage.

Answer (score 4):

Google Translate Kit, an open source library http://ggltranslate.codeplex.com/

```
Translator gt = new Translator();
/*using cache*/
DemoWriter dw = new DemoWriter();
gt.KeyGen = new SimpleKeyGen();
gt.CacheManager = new SimleCacheManager();
gt.Writer = dw;
Translator.TranslatedPost post = gt.GetTranslatedPost("Hello world", LanguageConst.ENGLISH, LanguageConst.CHINESE);
Translator.TranslatedPost post2 = gt.GetTranslatedPost("I'm Jeff", LanguageConst.ENGLISH, LanguageConst.CHINESE);
this.result.InnerHtml = "<p>" + post.text +post2.text+ "</p>";
dw.WriteToFile();
```

Answer (score 2):

When I used above code.It show me translated text as question mark like (???????).Then I convert from WebClient to HttpClient then I got a accurate result.So you can used code like this.

```
public static string TranslateText( string input, string languagePair)       
{
    string url = String.Format("http://www.google.com/translate_t?hl=en&ie=UTF8&text={0}&langpair={1}", input, languagePair);
    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
    string result = httpClient.GetStringAsync(url).Result;
    result = result.Substring(result.IndexOf("<span title=\"") + "<span title=\"".Length);
    result = result.Substring(result.IndexOf(">") + 1);
    result = result.Substring(0, result.IndexOf("</span>"));
    return result.Trim();
}
```

Then you Call a function like.You put first two letter of any language pair.

From English(en) To Urdu(ur).

```
TranslateText(line, "en|ur")
```

Comment: This was the best working solution.

Comment: Hi is this solution still working? In my case its not finding the "<span title..." on the returned html string.  Thank you.

Comment: This one works now: https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/5247661/Google-Translate-API-Usage-in-Csharp

Answer (score 1):

Here is my slighly different code, solving also the encoding issue:

```
public string TranslateText(string input, string languagePair)
{
    string url = String.Format("http://www.google.com/translate_t?hl=en&ie=UTF8&text={0}&langpair={1}", input, languagePair);
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
    webClient.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.Default;
    string result = webClient.DownloadString(url);
    result = result.Substring(result.IndexOf("TRANSLATED_TEXT"));
    result = result.Substring(result.IndexOf("'")+1);
    result = result.Substring(0, result.IndexOf("'"));
    return result;
}
```

Example of the function call:

```
var input_language = "en";
var output_language = "es";
var result = TranslateText("Hello", input_language + "|" + output_language);
```

The result will be "Hola"

Comment: Not works. says `System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.`

Answer (score 0):

Google is going to shut the translate API down by the end of 2011, so you should be looking at the alternatives!

Comment: There is a paid for v2 version which has not been discontinued.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to translate your **resources**, just download MAT (Multilingual App Toolkit) for Visual Studio. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MultilingualAppToolkit.MultilingualAppToolkit-18308 
This is the way to go to translate your projects in Visual Studio.
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/matdev/