# Translation Service that can be used from ASP.NET application

Tags: c#, asp.net, translation, google-translate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# - google translate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246017/c-sharp-google-translate)

I am looking for a web service or an API that I can use to translate text from one language to the other. The size of the text will be limited to 10,000 characters. I understand that Google and Babelfish have websites to do this. But I need to integrate it as a part of my web application.

Any ideas how to proceed?

PS: I am not looking for any paid service.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246017/c-google-translate

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[Using Google Translate in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246017/c-google-translate)

Answer (score 2):

You can use Google Translation API for .NET [link](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-for-dotnet/)
or Use Microsoft Translator V2 APIs [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff512423.aspx)