# English to french asp.net resource file translation

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a asp.net resouce language file in english and I have to translate that resource file into french. how can this be achieved? There are lot of values on the resource file that needs to be translated.

is there any sample available on how this can be done by using google language translation or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Copy the entire contents of your resource file to Excel;
2. Copy the entire contents of the second column from Excel to Google Translate;
3. Copy the translated strings back to the second column of Excel;
4. Clear out your resource file;
5. Copy the entire contents from Excel back to your resource file.

Hope this helps. Should be easier than doing this programmatically.

Comment: Is there any program that reads the english resource file and gives out the french file or any other language specific file?

Comment: Pieter your idea sounds good if the program option doesn't work out. Thanks!!

Comment: Why won't the above work for you? Maybe that can help finding a utility that works for you.

Comment: I am planning to write a utility if the utility is not available. I am thinking of achieving this programmatically

Comment: Then http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246017/c-google-translate should probably help.

Answer (score 2):

pay a translator, and to edit the resource files there's [Zeta Resource Editor](http://www.zeta-resource-editor.com/index.html) which is pretty usefull

Answer (score 0):

Google Translate will do the job.  It has a limit on the number of requests it'll accept within a given period of time.

I've used it to translate a web site from Japanese Kanji to English.  It did pretty well.

Comment: is there a sample program that I can use?

Answer (score 0):

Download MAT (Multilingual App Toolkit) for Visual Studio.
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MultilingualAppToolkit.MultilingualAppToolkit-18308

This is the way to go to translate your projects in Visual Studio ;-)

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/matdev/