# How to translate from English to french using C#

Tags: c#

I have the following code

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ResXResourceReader resourceReader = new ResXResourceReader("EN-US.resx");

        foreach (DictionaryEntry dictonary in resourceReader)
        {
            //call google API to translate the entry
            MessageBox.Show(dictonary.Key.ToString() + ":\t" + dictonary.Value.ToString());
        }

        resourceReader.Close();
    }
```

In the above example I am reading a resource file and display it on the messagebox. I need to know how can I call google webservice or something and translate the entire resource file to a new language (french in my case) Please do let me know. I appreciate your support.

Comment: This is not maintainable, they'll break your app without notice.

Comment: Not possible. Hire professional translators instead.

Comment: You want to call Google Translate at run-time for every single static string you have?!?

Comment: I would advise against doing this in anything other than a just-for-fun application. Automatic translation will make your application look very cheap.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a .NET API for this. Check http://code.google.com/p/google-language-api-for-dotnet/ for a specific one. [Using Google Translate in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246017/c-google-translate) has a list of available options.

Comment: Doing that for static strings though is absurd.

Comment: He wants to store it to a new resource file. This is quite reasonable if you don't mind crappy translations.

Comment: Ah, my bad. I interpreted that as calling Google Translate upon displaying a message box. Okay, better, although the translations are still going to be pretty whack. I guess that's certainly okay for a free application, but most likely not for a professional product.

Comment: I have an application with so many resources files and the client wanted the website to be in french. So i am trying to come up with a utility by which I can read the resource file and translate and save it. Pieter already gave me an other option which involves manual work. It is in a seperate thread.

Answer (score 0):

Download MAT (Multilingual App Toolkit) for Visual Studio.
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MultilingualAppToolkit.MultilingualAppToolkit-18308

This is the way to go to translate your projects in Visual Studio ;-)