# Internationalise silverlight app

Tags: asp.net, silverlight

can we make multilingual silverlight app without resource files?

Because i m my website i m using google translate api, but there is problem in silverlight translation.

Thanks!!!

Comment: "there is [a] problem in silverlight translation" - can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246017/c-google-translate) has a wealth of resources regarding [calling Google Translate from .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246017/c-google-translate).

The main one is [Google API for DotNet](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-for-dotnet/) which has a Silverlight 3 version of the Google Translate API.

If none of those fit the bill then you'll need to improve your question to describe the actual problem.