# Translate text in other languages in asp.net C# web application

Tags: asp.net, web-services, c#-4.0, google-api

I want to translate text in Indian languages. I have gone through many articles but can not understand clearly how to do so. I have also seen some articles on google translator but none of them provide guide to use it in code.
Please guide me how can I do so. Do I need to add fonts for all languages in my application?

I have pasted the following code and now getting error. Can't understand what is that error.
The error is "Index and length must refer to a location within the string.
Parameter name: length".

Below is my code.

```
 public string TranslateText(string input, string languagePair)
 {
    string url = String.Format("http://www.google.com/translate_t?hl=en&ie=UTF8&text={0}&langpair={1}", input, languagePair);
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
    webClient.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
    string result = webClient.DownloadString(url);
    result = result.Substring(result.IndexOf("id=result_box") + 22, result.IndexOf("id=result_box") + 500);
    result = result.Substring(0, result.IndexOf("</div"));
    return result;
}
protected void btnTranslate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string convertTo="en|"+ddlLanguages.SelectedValue;
    txtTarget.Text = TranslateText(txtLanguage.Text, convertTo);
}
```

ID of both the textboxes are "txtLanguage" for source language and "txtTarget" for target language.

Comment: are you trying to make Multilingual website or just want to translate some text in a different language?

Comment: Just want to translate to other language.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not try these?

**google-language-api-for-dotnet**

http://code.google.com/p/google-language-api-for-dotnet/

**Translate text in C#, using Google Translate**

http://dnknormark.net/post/Translate-text-in-C-using-Google-Translate.aspx

**Google Translator**

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/GoogleTranslator.aspx

**Translate your text using Google Api's**

http://blogs.msdn.com/shahpiyush/archive/2007/06/09/3188246.aspx

**Calling Google Ajax Language API for Translation and Language Detection from C#**

http://www.esotericdelights.com/post/2008/11/Calling-Google-Ajax-Language-API-for-Translation-and-Language-Detection-from-C.aspx

**Translation Web Service in C#**

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/translation.aspx

Using Google's Translation API from .NET

http://www.reimers.dk/blogs/jacob_reimers_weblog/archive/2008/06/18/using-google-s-translation-api-from-net.aspx

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246017/c-sharp-google-translate)

Answer (score 0):

The application needs a XML FIle with words and keys. I created a folder "Globalization" to input XML files with dictionary list

[image]

The XML file scructure is bellow

[image]

[image]

[image]
Class translate configurations

```
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
public class TranslateConfigurations
{
    public string Extension { get; set; } = ".xml";
    public string Culture { get { return Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.Name; } }
    public string Path { get; set; } = @$"{Directory.GetCurrentDirectory().Split("bin")[0]}\Globalization\";
}
```

This is a method to translate strings inside a XML dictionary in application path.

```
using domain.translate.Configurations;
using domain.translate.Contracts.Business;
using domain.translate.Utilities;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;

public class TranslateBusiness : ITranslateBusiness
{
    private readonly ILogger<string> _logger;
    private readonly TranslateConfigurations _translateConfiguration;

    /// <summary>
    ///     
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="logger"></param>
    public TranslateBusiness(ILogger<string> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _translateConfiguration = new TranslateConfigurations();
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Translate string with string culture
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="wordKey"></param>
    /// <param name="culture"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public object Translate(string wordKey, string strCulture)
    {
        try
        {
            var culture = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(strCulture) ? new CultureInfo(strCulture) : throw new CultureNotFoundException();

            return Messages.GenerateGenericSuccessObjectMessage("Translate", GetXmlSection(wordKey, culture.Name), 200);
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            _logger.LogError(e.Message ?? e.InnerException.Message, null);
            return Messages.GenerateGenericErrorMessage($"Não existe o arquivo de tradução '{strCulture}'.", 404, wordKey);
        }
        catch (CultureNotFoundException e)
        {
            _logger.LogError(e.Message ?? e.InnerException.Message, null);
            return Messages.GenerateGenericErrorMessage($"Não existe a cultura '{strCulture}'.", 404, wordKey);
        }
        catch (KeyNotFoundException e)
        {
            _logger.LogError(e.Message ?? e.InnerException.Message, null);
            return Messages.GenerateGenericErrorMessage($"Não existe a chave '{wordKey}' no arquivo de tradução.", 404, wordKey);
        }
        catch (DirectoryNotFoundException e)
        {
            _logger.LogError(e.Message ?? e.InnerException.Message, null);
            return Messages.GenerateGenericErrorMessage($"Não existe o caminho do arquivo de tradução.", 404, wordKey);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            _logger.LogError(e.Message ?? e.InnerException.Message, null);
            return (e.Message != null && e?.InnerException?.Message != null) ? Messages.GenerateGenericErrorMessage(e.Message, e.InnerException.Message) : Messages.GenerateGenericErrorMessage(e.Message ?? e.InnerException.Message);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Translate string list with string culture
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="wordKeys"></param>
    /// <param name="culture"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public object Translate(List<string> wordKeys, string strCulture)
    {
        try
        {
            var culture = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(strCulture) ? new CultureInfo(strCulture) : throw new CultureNotFoundException();

            return Messages.GenerateGenericSuccessObjectMessage("Translate", GetXmlSection(wordKeys, culture.Name), 200);
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            _logger.LogError(e.Message ?? e.InnerException.Message, null);
            return Messages.GenerateGenericErrorMessage($"Não existe o arquivo de tradução '{strCulture}'.", 404);
        }
        catch (CultureNotFoundException e)
        {
            _logger.LogError(e.Message ?? e.InnerException.Message, null);
            return Messages.GenerateGenericErrorMessage($"Não existe a cultura '{strCulture}'.", 404, wordKeys);
        }
        catch (KeyNotFoundException e)
        {
            _logger.LogError(e.Message ?? e.InnerException.Message, null);
            return Messages.GenerateGenericErrorMessage($"Não existem as chaves no arquivo de tradução.", 404, wordKeys);
        }
        catch (DirectoryNotFoundException e)
        {
            _logger.LogError(e.Message ?? e.InnerException.Message, null);
            return Messages.GenerateGenericErrorMessage($"Não existe o caminho do arquivo de tradução.", 404);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            _logger.LogError(e.Message ?? e.InnerException.Message, null);
            return (e.Message != null && e?.InnerException?.Message != null) ? Messages.GenerateGenericErrorMessage(e.Message, e.InnerException.Message) : Messages.GenerateGenericErrorMessage(e.Message ?? e.InnerException.Message);
        }
    }

    #region Private methods

    /// <summary>
    ///     Get 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="key"></param>
    /// <param name="culture"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private string GetXmlSection(string key, string culture = null)
    {
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load($"{_translateConfiguration.Path}{culture ??_translateConfiguration.Culture}{_translateConfiguration.Extension}");
        var section = doc.Descendants().ToList().Where(n => n.FirstAttribute.Value == key);
        return section.FirstOrDefault()?.Value ?? throw new KeyNotFoundException();
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="keys"></param>
    /// <param name="culture"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private Dictionary<string, string> GetXmlSection(List<string> keys, string culture = null)
    {
        var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load($"{_translateConfiguration.Path}{culture ?? _translateConfiguration.Culture}{_translateConfiguration.Extension}");

        foreach (var key in keys)
        {
            var section = doc.Descendants().ToList().Where(n => n.FirstAttribute.Value == key);
            dictionary.Add(key, section.FirstOrDefault().Value);
        }

        return dictionary.Count > 0 ? dictionary : throw new KeyNotFoundException();
    }

    #endregion Private methods
}
```

Message class

```
public static class Messages
{
    public static object GenerateGenericSuccessObjectMessage(string propertyName, object objectResult, int statusCode)
    {
        var property = new ExpandoObject() as IDictionary<string, object>;
        property.Add("Code", statusCode);
        property.Add(propertyName, objectResult);

        return property;
    }

    public static object GenerateGenericErrorMessage(string message, int statusCode, object objectResult)
    {
        return new { Error = new { Code = statusCode, Translate = objectResult, Message = message } };
    }

    public static object GenerateGenericErrorMessage(string message, int statusCode)
    {
        return new { Error = new { Code = statusCode, Message = message } };
    }

    public static object GenerateGenericErrorMessage(string message)
    {
        return new { Error = new { Code = 400, Message = message } };
    }
```

}