# Multilingual website with dynamic content

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, multilingual

I am developing a survey website and I want to make it multilingual. Now, as survey questions are loaded dynamically from database, I can not use resource files to solve this problem.

Is there any built in library for C# which is capable of translating page content?

Comment: Are you haveing same survey in different languages?  If your questions are in database, does your database have those same questions in database in various languages (if so, just read the right record based on language context).  Or are you talking about have questions in one language, and then have some sort of means to translate those on the fly (like a call to Google Translate or something similar)?  Please clarify

Comment: @LB2 : Yes, you guessed correct. I want to translate those questions on the fly. As I am having large number of questions and I want them in about 10 to 12 languages, I don't want to create questions in each language and store them in database.

Comment: I tried SS Google translation API and get ahead in project but now I found that many of the translations are not natural. How can I get reed of this ? Even on Google translation, it's not natural. I heard of term "Online NLP", Can it be useful in my scenario ?

Comment: No need to get rid of this question as it may be useful to others.  AFAIK automated translators won't be perfect, though some are better and some are worse.  If you find a tool/package/service that does it better, you'll have to work with their API, whatever that may be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246017/c-sharp-google-translate).  Also [this project](http://ssgoogletranslation.codeplex.com/).

Comment: SS Google translation API worked for me. I created sample demo project and all went perfect. Thanks..!!

Answer (score 0):

You could store the sentences in a database. If you want to use 3 languages, you will need 3 rows: id, language1, language2. Then all you have to do is to refer to them with id and customize it with the SQL query. E.g.: SELECT language1 FROM translations WHERE id=1

Other way for this is to use a built in Google Translate, but in lot of cases its translations are not so good.

Comment: As stated in my comment, I have 10 to 12 languages. so storing questions in database will not be a good option in my case

Comment: You should store them somewhere or use a built in Google Translate and guess that's not the option you want to use.
You can store it in database or either in xml, there is no better option I think.