# How to download language packs on PC in order to use offline Google Translate?

Tags: c#, translation, google-translate, language-packs

I want to use offline Google Translate application.
I know that it is possible to download language packs on Android smartphones, but i need to do this on my windows desktop machine.

Also I found some Google translate API`s which allows me to use online Google Translation in my .NET application!

[Using Google Translate in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246017/c-sharp-google-translate)
https://code.google.com/p/google-language-api-for-dotnet/

But what about offline translation?
Will it allow me to do offline translation as well?
Of-course if I have this large files called language packs?
Is it possible?
How?

Answer (score 3):

Here is an answer of this question but it is only about downloading any language pack.

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2234606

As we can see before downloading any language packs, there is two Core files which is necessary!

http://dl.google.com/translate/offline/v3/r1/c.zip
http://dl.google.com/translate/offli...1/profiles.txt

Then we should download any language pack. Just like this ....

http://dl.google.com/translate/offline/v3/r1/****.zip