# Translate content of a XML File

Tags: xml, translate

Example of the lines below

```
<LiuShui ID="17" Name="普通亚昆毒雾消除" AIID="61" TriggerNum="-1" TriggerCD="-1" TriggerType="5" Condition="2101" Action="CLEAR_GUANGMUI(1,21)" Description="亚昆兵全部死亡光幕消失"></LiuShui>
<LiuShui ID="18" Name="亚昆魔王小怪召唤首领" AIID="61" TriggerNum="-1" TriggerCD="-1" TriggerType="5" Condition="2101" Action="BOSS_CALLMONSTERTWO(2100,1,3450,4850,1)" Description="亚昆魔王出现在秘境深处"></LiuShui>
```

What i need to do is, translate only the text between **Name=""** and **Description=""**

Which method or tool you guys recommend to me?

Comment: What do you mean by "translate"? What have you tried and how did it fail?

Comment: The stack is limiting my text, i don't know why. Everything i write he consider as spam... 

the first part of the text was "I'm translating a .xml that some words are in chinese, and  i need it in english, but i can't do it manually because have alot of lines and would takes ages, so i need a method or a automatic tool to translate it, there no problem in using google translator.
"

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can desirialize your XML, than translate it using Google Translate and serialize it back. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246017/using-google-translate-in-c-sharp) is how to use Google Translate in C#.

Comment: answer is too general, please try avoiding using links

Comment: i have read and still not what a looking for. I need to translate what is inside a tag. Like Name="I need translate what is inside this"