# Winforms translate back to English

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms

I have application written in Winform(c#) with roughly 40-50 forms, every form has a .resx file for French language.

I want my application forms (texts, buttons etc) to be in English. I can do that manually but is there a simple, quicker way of doing it.

Comment: see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246017/using-google-translate-in-c-sharp)

Comment: *someone* needs to translate those strings, an automatic translation will fail

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the resources in resx files, just add resx files for english and translate them. Then set the CurrentUICulture to english and all the strings will come from the english resources instead of the default ones.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa992030.aspx

Comment: Actually this is what I am trying to avoid because there are so many .RESX files and it will do take time to convert so many files.

Comment: Well... you're not converting are you? Just making copies of those files. Then modify the copies. I should have mentioned this to be honest.