# How To Write Urdu String C#

Tags: c#, android, .net, xamarin

I am developing android app to send pre-defined sms in urdu. I successfully send in english but **I need to know that how can i write urdu string in C#**

I know a way to convert each urdu character **UTF_8** to string, e.g.

```
char aleph ;
char ra;
char dal;
char wao;
string word;
aleph = '\u0627';
ra = '\u0631';
dal = '\u062F';
wao = '\u0648';
word = aleph.ToString() + ra.ToString()+dal.ToString()+ wao.ToString();
```

As described [Here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1134/Multilingual-Support-in-C)
But its a very hectic way, is there another way around?

Or is there a way to translate English string to Urdu in C#?

Comment: Android and C#? your question need some more explanation

Comment: i am developing using xamarin with visual studio using c#

Comment: In C#, you can put all the UTF_8 characters in one string:
string s="\u0627\u0631\u0046";

Comment: C# strings can contain Urdu without any need for encoding or translation. `var s = "ہیلو"`. Note that any string in any language can be displayed left-aligned or right-aligned, is that what you are trying to do? Please explain what your goal is, not just what you are doing.

Comment: you can use to translate the english string using google translator to Urdu 
use api of google translator or another way as you think better.
following link may help asked before here 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246017/using-google-translate-in-c-sharp

Comment: @DourHighArch i have mentioned in my question that i am developing android app to send pre-defined sms in urdu, how can i right align urdu?

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeColette it helps out but how can i align the text to right because urdu starts from right to left

Answer (score 0):

Umar, salaams

As already stated, just set the string to the Urdu text you need.

But if what you are asking is about how to display an Urdu keyboard for text entry you have to change the device's culture.

Here is a link on the subject:https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/9764/how-to-set-a-global-cultureinfo-for-an-app

scroll down to the answer about how to do this for Android.