# Culture invariant bool.TryParse

Tags: c#, .net, boolean, tryparse

It might sound weird, stupid or whatever, but I was curious about finding a "native" way to make the `bool.TryParse(string s, out bool result)` method invariant culture.

It of course works if the input to be parsed is `"true"` or `"false"` but it would always return false as the parsing result if something like `"verdadero"`, `"wahr"` or `"falso"` would be passed.

I haven't found anything on the MSDN related to this, but is there any way to make that [bool.TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.boolean.tryparse?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Boolean_TryParse_System_String_System_Boolean__) InvariantCulture'd?

Comment: It's already "tied" to the Invariant Culture, the only two recognized values are `Boolean.TrueString` and `Boolean.FalseString`. Do you need an hypotetical `Parse()` method which accepts **localized** string values? You have to write it by your own...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A funny approach could be this. I found this nice piece of translation code:

```
public static string TranslateText( string input, string languagePair)
{
    string url = String.Format("http://www.google.com/translate_t?hl=en&ie=UTF8&text={0}&langpair={1}", input, languagePair);
    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
    string result = httpClient.GetStringAsync(url).Result;
    result = result.Substring(result.IndexOf("<span title=\"") + "<span title=\"".Length);
    result = result.Substring(result.IndexOf(">") + 1);
    result = result.Substring(0, result.IndexOf("</span>"));
    return result.Trim();
}
```

on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50231085/5174469)

You could use it like this:

```
bool output;

Boolean.TryParse(TranslateText("wahr", "de|en"), out output);
Console.WriteLine($"German Output: {output}");

Boolean.TryParse(TranslateText("verdadero", "esp|en"), out output);
Console.WriteLine($"Spanish Output: {output}");

Boolean.TryParse(TranslateText("falso", "it|en"), out output);
Console.WriteLine($"Italian Output: {output}");
```

It gives you the following output:

> German Output: True
>   Spanish Output: True
>   Italian Output: False

Its more of a playfull approach. ;)

EDIT:

For this purpose you could also use `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`

```
Boolean.TryParse(TranslateText("wahr", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture + "|en"), out output);
Console.WriteLine($"{System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture} Output: {output}");
Boolean.TryParse(TranslateText("falsch", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture + "|en"), out output);
Console.WriteLine($"{System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture} Output: {output}");
```

and it works actually! Output:

> de-DE Output: True
>   de-DE Output: False

Answer (score 0):

If you are really worried about Invariant culture issue you can first try to convert it

```
string sNew = s.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

bool.TryParse(string sNew, out bool result)
```