# Translate Resource Files To different language

Tags: c#, google-translate

Hello I am wanting to translate resource files into a new language. I have looked into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246017/using-google-translate-in-c-sharp) however it doesn't seem to work any more. I was wondering if there is a new way.

I have also found [this](https://help.memsource.com/hc/en-us/articles/115003461051-How-To-Get-Google-Translate-API-Key-And-Start-Using-Google-NMT-in-Memsource) which seems overkill as you have to pay for it. I have maybe 10 files to translate, and 100 items on each file. Is there a good way to do this pragmatically?

Comment: What I'm about to say is not programatically, but... there is an amazing plugin for Visual Studio called [ResXManager](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TomEnglert.ResXManager) that can do translations for you using Google Translate as one of the translation endpoints. Look at [Automatic Translations](https://github.com/tom-englert/ResXResourceManager/wiki/Automatic-Translations) documentation page for usage.

Answer (score 2):

You need an actual bi-lingual human for this.

Machine translation is mostly understandable, but people will know what you did and ridicule you for it unless you're going between closely related languages or languages where Google has a lot of training data.

Google Translate does work. [You just need to use their API.](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/translating-text#translate_translate_text-csharp) and [provide credentials](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production)

**edit**

> I have maybe 10 files to translate, and 100 items on each file.

If you really only have 10 files to translate, and only need to do it once, and don't mind a machine translation, you can copy and paste them into https://translate.google.com/

Comment: but yes probably once for each.

Comment: It's your decision wheter you use the API or copy and paste.

Answer (score 0):

You can find sample code for using the Translation API C# library and the steps to set up all prerequisites, including passing your credentials to the library in this [quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/quickstart-client-libraries). For additional options, you may refer to the library’s [reference](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/Google.Cloud.Translation.V2/).